# Managing contents of tabular and width of cells

Tags: latex

Hello I need to recrate this table in Latex.

[image]

This is the "code" I wrote

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\hskip-4.0cm\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
   Lp. & Kryterium klasyfikacji & Rodzaj (klasa) modelu \\
   \hline
   1 & \begin{tabular}{l} Struktura modelu\\ i przedmiot modelowania\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
   \begin{tabular}{c}modele\\pojedyńczych\\procesów\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c}modele\\komponentów\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c}modele\\integralne\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c}modele\\globalne
   \end{tabular} \\
   \end{tabular}  \\ 
\hline
2&Stosowane metody badawcze&\begin{tabular}{c|c}modele genetyczne & modele statystyczne \end{tabular} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And it looks like this

[image]

The way I did this is really tiresome and kinda dumb. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? I also can't figure out how to make the middle line in 3rd column connect through 3 rows like in the reference picture

[image]

I would really appreciate some kind of already started table so i can recreate the method further along as i do next rows

Comment: Instead of manually splitting the cells, make one table with 6 columns and then merge the cells which should span more than one column

Comment: ... and use a fixed width column type instead of doing the line breaks manually

Comment: Can you add a compilable [mre] instead of this code fragment?

Comment: Now it is compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually splitting the cells, make one table with 6 columns and then merge the cells which should span more than one column:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\linewidth}}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{|c|d{.23}|d{.21}|d{.15}|d{.11}|d{.11}|}
\hline
Lp. & Kryterium klasyfikacji & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Rodzaj (klasa) modelu} \\\hline
1 & Struktura modelu i przedmiot modelowania & modele pojedyńczych procesów & modele komponentów & modele integralne & modele globalne\\\hline
2 & Stosowane metody badawcze & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele genetyczne} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{modele statystyczne}\\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, this is cool and i like how it looks only 1 thing is bothering me. "modele genetyczne" and "modele statystyczne" are kinda high in the cell is there any way to make them centered?

Comment: @antekkalafior check now

Comment: It works now :) What did u change? I can't spot the difference

Comment: @antekkalafior I replaced the top aligned `p` column with a centre aligned `m` column